# Is it possible to use variables in PIL (python)?

Tags: python, variables, text, python-imaging-library, draw

i'm programing in python 3.1 and using a PIL which are updated for it aswel.
Now it's so that my program is getting info from a webpage and i want this info to be drawed at a picture which i already got, so i'm using a variable for this & it's also the part i need help with.
What I link is a part of my program (since it's over 100 lines i'm just showing the parts which i found realative to the question)

```
import webbrowser
import random
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import re
import PIL
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

arial16 = ImageFont.truetype ("arial.ttf", 16)

Z = (input ("What is the character name? "))

#The link which i get from my input info..
url = "http://"+X+".battle.net/wow/en/character/"+Y+"/"+Z+"/simple"

# Read the webpage
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

# Encoding
encoding = "utf-8"
html =html.decode (encoding)

# Find right class & choose background from it
cl = re.findall ('class="class">(.*)</a><span class="comma">,</span>', html) 

if "Death Knight" : im = Image.open ("DeathKnightBackground.png")
elif "Druid" : im = Image.open ("DruidBackground.png")
elif "Hunter" : im = Image.open ("HunterBackground.png")
elif "Mage" : im = Image.open ("MageBackground.png")
elif "Paladin" : im = Image.open ("PaladinBackground.png")
elif "Priest" : im = Image.open ("PriestBackground.png")
elif "Rogue" : im = Image.open ("RogueBackground.png")
elif "Shaman" : im = Image.open ("ShamanBackground.png")
elif "Warlock" : im = Image.open ("WarlockBackground.png")
elif "Warrior" : im = Image.open ("WarriorBackground.png")

# Find the Title
title = re.findall('<div class="title">(.*)</div>', html)

# If i want to print this i just do
print (("Your Charactername with it's title:")+Z, title)
print (("You are:"),cl)

# Then i want to use a variable to save my picture
S = input("Please enter a name to save your forumsignature: ")

# When i want to draw the text to the picture i tried to use (+Z, title) as in the print
# function - but since this didn't work i will just go with ((+Z, title)) which don't give me
# syntax error

draw = ImageDraw.Draw ( im )
draw.text ( (20,20), ((+ Z, title)), font=arial16, fill="white")

# As i said before, i'm using variable S for saving and tried this way.. but in all the ways i
# have tried, i always keep getting syntax errors 

im.save ((+S))

im.show ((+S))
```

So does anyone know if PIL are able to work with variables in this kind of way? or does you know some other way to draw text from variables at an image with python 3.1?

Very cheerful for replies and i will keep trying to test all kind of different ways i know to get this to work & post up here if i get something to work...

// Zabs

Comment: Your `if` statements aren't going to do much since the string "Death Knight" will always evaluate to `True`.  You may want: `if "Death Knight" in cl:`

Comment: Which way exactly are you wondering if you can use variables?

Comment: Guessing is not a good way to do programming. You've done some guesswork in how to use the `if` statement, and how to use variables. It's best if you began with a Python manual that explained these things in detail. -> http://diveintopython3.org/ When you learn Python it would be clear how to do the things that bother you. Also by using regular expressions to extract info from HTML you're "guessing" the structure. You should use `lxml.html` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a syntax error. Adding more parenthesis just makes a new datastructure. Try:

```
text = Z + " " + title
draw.text ( (20,20), text, font=arial16, fill="white")
```

and for your save command:

```
im.save(S)
im.show(S)
```